# Having two full-screen UIViews vertically in a single UIVIewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am looking for a way to have two Full-Screen UIViews in a single Viewcontroller in such a way that there will be a button and when the user hits the button, it takes it to the view bellow the first view and vice versa...In a simpler word, I want to put two full-screen UIViews vertically in a single UIViewcontroller

I am looking for something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want a visual effect when transitioning between the views?  A uiscrollview is the common way to present more views than will fit at once.  This can have scrolling (for the user) turned off, and have the app perform the scroll -- either up or down a full page -- when the button is pressed.

Comment: A small scrolling effect (like not too much) would be nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a scrollview for that scenario. add the two views as subviews to the scrollview and update the scrollview's contentoffset when the user taps the button (or in my example a segmented control):

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    self.scrollView = scrollView

    let firstView = UIView()
    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(firstView)

    let secondView = UIView()
    secondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    secondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    scrollView.addSubview(secondView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[sv]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["sv": scrollView]))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[sv]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["sv": scrollView]))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|[fv]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["fv": firstView]))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[fv][sv]|", options: [.AlignAllLeading, .AlignAllTrailing], metrics: nil, views: ["fv": firstView, "sv": secondView]))

    firstView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true
    firstView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.heightAnchor).active = true

    firstView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(secondView.widthAnchor).active = true
    firstView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(secondView.heightAnchor).active = true

    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: ["firstView", "secondView"])
    segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    segmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[sc]-20-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["sc": segmentedControl]))

    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
}

func segmentedControlValueChanged(segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, CGFloat(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) * scrollView.frame.height), animated: true)
}
```

hope i got you right. feel free to ask if anything is unclear!

**UPDATE (OBJ-C)**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    self.scrollView = scrollView;

    UIView *firstView = [UIView new];
    firstView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:firstView];

    UIView *secondView = [UIView new];
    secondView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    [scrollView addSubview:secondView];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[sv]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"sv": scrollView}]];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[sv]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"sv": scrollView}]];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[fv]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"fv": firstView}]];
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[fv][sv]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading|NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTrailing metrics:nil views:@{@"fv": firstView, @"sv": secondView}]];

    [firstView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:scrollView.widthAnchor].active = YES;
    [firstView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:scrollView.heightAnchor].active = YES;

    [firstView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secondView.widthAnchor].active = YES;
    [firstView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:secondView.heightAnchor].active = YES;

    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"firstView", @"secondView"]];
    segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[sc]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"sc": segmentedControl}]];

    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

- (void)segmentedControlValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex * CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame)) animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, do you by any chance have the same code base in Obj-C?

Comment: Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UITableView` of 2 cells, each cell taking up the whole screen (look up how to set height dynamically).

You could have 2 custom cells, one for each view, which would have its own class & logic obviously.

That would work, you'd be able to use various scrollview advantages, like snapping on the top of the view to avoid having only part of the view displayed, or manually controlling the scroll.

Also, you would be future proof in case you need to change the number of views : you could have as many as you want !

They could also be larger/smaller than the size of the screen, since they're in a scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple really provided you use `autoLayout`. Drag and drop a `UIView` onto your storyboard and add a leading, trailing, bottom and top to the superView. Lets call this *view1*. Now drag and drop another `UIView` onto your storyboard at the same heirarchy level as the *view1*, lets call this new view, *view2*. Now set the y offset in size inspector for your *view2* to be lets say 800.

Now in your view heirarchy, <kbd>control</kbd> + click *view1* and drag and drop onto your *view2* and press <kbd>shift</kbd> and select leading, trailing, vertical spacing and equal height constraint. Ensure all constants are set to 0 (Set the equal height constraint priority to 250, if you want the height inferred based on the content and not be equal to the full screen height).

Your screen should now look like this:

[image]

Now select your *view1* and choose the top constraint. The one attached to the superview. Create an outlet for this constraint into your `UIViewController` class and lets call it `viewOneTopSpaceConstraint`.

Now all you have to do is, inside the `IBAction` for the *toggle* button just:

```
if viewOneTopSpaceConstraint.constant == 0{

     viewOneTopSpaceConstraint.constant = -UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
}else{

     viewOneTopSpaceConstraint.constant = 0
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {

     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

One last option although all answers I have read are good is to give the user the feeling that one view is offscreen while the other is on while basically pinning everything to the superview.  Here is my setup and using CATransitions.
[image: Setup]

The master container is pinned to the main view but you could add space at the top if controls are supposed to go there.  It contains 2 views that are both pinned to the masterContainer.  Both have a button to call the change.  I preset in storyboard view2 to be hidden when the app launches.  Here is the controller.  When you press the button in view 1 view 2 will slide up from the bottom.  When you press view2 button view1 will slide view2 back down.  Here is the controller and the needed code.

```
import UIKit

class CATransitionDemoViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var masterContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        view2.isHidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func viewButton1DidPress(_ sender: Any) {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.4
            transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop
            self.masterContainer.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
            view1.isHidden = !view1.isHidden
            view2.isHidden = !view2.isHidden
    }

    @IBAction func viewButton2DidPress(_ sender: Any) {
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.4
            transition.type = kCATransitionPush
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
            self.masterContainer.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
            view1.isHidden = !view1.isHidden
            view2.isHidden = !view2.isHidden
    }
```

OR in Objective C

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *masterContainer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [_view2 setHidden:YES];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)buttonView1DidPress:(id)sender {
    CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc]init];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    //or for some real fun uncomment the next line and comment the two lines out after that one
    //transition.type = @"suckEffect";
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    [_masterContainer.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [_view1 setHidden:!_view1.hidden];
    [_view2 setHidden:!_view2.hidden];
}

- (IBAction)buttonView2DidPress:(id)sender {
    CATransition *transition = [[CATransition alloc]init];
    transition.duration = 0.5;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    [_masterContainer.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [_view1 setHidden:!_view1.hidden];
    [_view2 setHidden:!_view2.hidden];
}

@end
```

The advantage of this is that when you are working in storyboard everything will be easily accessible without the setup of a scrollview.  Plus there are a lot more options with CATransitions.

Comment: Is it possible for you to also share the source code in obj-c?